# Spring and thymeleaf set and get value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I send object `myObject` to view, one of values is put in `input` inside `form` with `post` method. How is it possible to set value to view and then get it by submit this form (but with another object type)?

I tried something like:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/myMethod}" th:object="${anotherObject}" method="post" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<input  style="display:none" type="text" th:name="*{fieldFromAnotherObject}" th:value="${sendedObject.fieldFromSendedObject}"/>
```

but the result is that `name` field in this html element is empty:
[image]

(value is correct). And then I have `null` as `fieldFromAnotherObject` field of `anotherObject` in my backend.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using two objects one for binding values to view and one for submitting,if both are of same class one object would be sufficient.Using th:field you can achieve this with single object. Try below code it should work.

```
  <form action="#" th:action="@{/myMethod}" th:object="${anotherObject}" method="post" >
  <input  style="display:none" type="text" th:field="*{fieldFromSendedObject}"/>
```

Just in case if both are of different class objects, try below code

```
  <input  style="display:none" type="text" th:name="anotherObject.fieldFromSendedObject" th:value="${sendedObject.fieldFromSendedObject}"/>
```